# Rapidminer FPGrowth returning subsets as well. I only need the maximum frequent item sets

Tags: r, groovy, data-mining, text-mining, rapidminer

Let me simplify my problem with sample Iris dataset. Here is the output I see with FPGrowth operator launched over Iris dataset:

[image]

See my notes in red, in this sample I only need a3_range1 and a2_range5 as well as all 3-item sets, because all the other ones are subsets of the larger sets.

Is there any way I can do it with the help of FPGrowth itself? Or do I have to workaround with ExecuteScript? In latter case, I can't seem to be able even import and iterate over the input after FPGrowth: if I do this:

```
ExampleSet exampleSet = operator.getInput(ExampleSet.class);
```

I'm getting "The operator needs some input of ExampleSet which is not provided". If I change it to:

```
FPGrowth exampleSet = operator.getInput(FPGrowth.class);
```

it complaints that it cannot resolve FPGrowth class.

How do I import it in ExecuteScript Groovy code?

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is the problem of mining **frequent maximal itemsets** rather than all frequent itemsets.

In the litterature, several algorithms have been proposed for this problem:  GenMax, LCMMax, FPMax, MAFIA, etc.  In particular, FPMax is based on FPGrowth.

But I don't think that they are implemented in the tool that you are using.

If efficiency is not important, you could do it by postprocessing. If efficiency is important you could use one of the above algorithm (perhaps implement them if they are not offered)

By the way, you could have a look at my [SPMF Java open-source data mining library](http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf), which offers more than 60 algorithms and is specialized for pattern mining. In particular, it offers an implementation of Charm-MFI to discovers maximal itemsets by post-processing on closed itemsets, thus avoiding exploring the search space of all frequent itemsets.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the following R script:

```
FPSet <- as.data.frame(FPSet)

trim <- function (x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)

for(i in 1:nrow(FPSet)) {
   current <- trim(unlist(strsplit(toString(FPSet[i,"Items"]),',')))

    for(j in 1:nrow(FPSet)) {
        if(i!=j) {
            compare <- trim(unlist(strsplit(toString(FPSet[j,"Items"]),',')))
            if(setequal(intersect(current,compare),current) || length(current) == 1) {
                 FPSet[i,'subset'] = 1
            }
        }
    }
}

FPSet<-FPSet[is.na(FPSet$subset), ]
FPSet$subset <- NULL
```

The `"Items"` column is where the subsets/sets are stored